# Making AJAX Applications crawlable without backend control

Tags: javascript, ajax, github, ember.js, seo

I've built a [tool](https://github.com/hodgesmr/Empress) that leverages EmberJS and GitHub Pages to create a blogging application that is rendered in-browser. It uses JavaScript to fetch Markdown files and render them into the body of the application. Because all content is fetched via AJAX requests, I'm not sure of the best way to make the content crawlable by Google, etc.

I've [read](http://www.pieterjongsma.com/2013/01/11/ember-google-ajax-rails.html) [many](https://vickev.com/#!/article/easily-index-your-single-page-application-thanks-to-phantomjs) [articles](http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/crawlable-ember-apps/465/7) that suggest using PhantomJS to handle the `_escaped_fragment_` requests, but since the content is hosted on GitHub, there's no way to run anything server-side.

Is there a possible work-around for this (such as rendering something ahead-of-time before pushing content to GitHub) or am I just experiencing the shortcomings of JavaScript applications?

Comment: The "server" is simply static Markdown files that are hosted on GitHub.

Comment: So, to go to your site, there is no `http://hodgesms.com/index.html`. Instead I load something from GitHub, store it on my computer and load the file into my browser? You dont' have a server for starting with and holding the links to the js? True?

Comment: An EmberJS application is hosted out on the web (say, on GitHub pages or any other host). That App, once loaded, makes an AJAX call to fetch Markdown files (the content) and displays them in the browser. Those files could be hosted on GitHub, or anywhere on the web, but no you don't download them to your computer and render the page. So yes, you could got to `http://hodgesmr.com` to get to the site.

Comment: I don't think you can get it crawled the way you describe. You have to have actual URLs with different path parts that get served up with content included to the crawler. Its going to require an active server of some sort to do that or generating the pages and storing them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is, [Can googlebot do basic javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9980824/can-googlebot-do-basic-javascript)

If not, then, no.  As I read you, your app requires JS support to render any page.  This leaves you without a bot-friendly access method.

If yes, then, yes:

Because JavaScript can access the url parameters via `location.search`, you can create plausible URLs for Google to fetch in `href` attributes which are interpreted by your JS app, and overridden for users in `onclick` attributes.

```
<a href="/?a=My-Blog-Post" onclick="someFunc(this.href);return false;">
```

This would be paired with code in your app's onload to seek `location.search` and fetch which .md may appear in the designated url parameter (after you parse the query string) in hopes that Google is running said onload to get the specified content.  This is a variant of many sites' `domain.com/#!ajax/path` style pathing.  Both are completely client side, but the query string variant will indicate to googlebot that the page is worth fetching as a distinct URL.

You may be able to test this with http://google.com/webmasters, which has a "fetch as googlebot" feature.

Comment: Thanks. I'm picking this as the answer because I think the real answer actually is "no". Since the crawlers don't execute any JS, it seems unlikely this would really work without a complete rewrite of the application.

Answer (score 1):

I created a small module that helps it. 's a look at http://alexferreira.github.io/seojs/

Comment: I was looking at this. Does it require a backend to run PhantomJS or can all of that work be done ahead of time and just push static files out?

Answer (score 1):

Without a backend server doing some logic it makes it a bit tricky...

But maybe, inspired by what is talked about here http://meta.discourse.org/t/seo-compared-to-other-well-known-tools/3914 and http://eviltrout.com/2013/06/19/adding-support-for-search-engines-to-your-javascript-applications.html

You could use your build script to generate copies of your index file in a tree following your routes definition `post/:post_slug` like `/post/slug/index.html`. Each page would have a `<noscript>` tag with very basic content and links of the current post. You could even have your `CurrentPost` JSON hash preloaded in the page to save some XHR.

That means using the History API which is not very IE friendly, but maybe not a big issue.

Answer (score 0):

You approached your supper eating your desert and then staring down at your vegetables.

What you really want to do is have the pages be served without AJAX first. Once you've got the pages loading correctly without the need for JavaScript then simply add a `?ajax=1` too all of your requests. If `isset($_GET['ajax'])` then you can avoid loading headers, footers, sidebars, etc. Then simply use an anonymous `window.onclick` and plug away from there.

Example video of Web 3.0 technology without using any third party software (including frameworks) all built using the strictest code that you're attempting to create...

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hZw8t-GVCB4

Feel free to look at the JavaScript on my site. I'll be happy to help you along over the course of this weekend.

Comment: I'm not using any backend code to serve these pages. I can't do `isset($_GET['ajax'])`

Answer (score -2):

U've a build script, so why not use PhantomJs there, to generate static web pages?

U can provide the static pages normally, and redirect to the AJAX page if JS is enabled.

The only point is, that a Ember-router-hyperlink is not avaliable for the search engine bots. But I think there is absolutly no way to handle this, without server code!